# Como passar o conteúdo de uma String (que peguei do View.toString() ) para uma View?

Tags: android

Eu usei o "View.toString" para pegar o conteúdo de uma string e salvar no SharedPreferences, já que preciso salvar a view lá dentro e o SharedPreferences só aceita tipo primitivo, mas agora eu preciso setar esta String em uma view que crei. É possível fazer isso? sei que deve ter algum método específico mas não estou conseguindo descobrir qual. Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Olá ! Poderia explicar melhor o seu problema? Você quer salvar um view? Ou pegar o valor da String em outra View?

Comment: Eu tenho uma view onde eu transformei ela em String utilizando o "View.toString" e salvei esta String utilizando o SharedPreferences. Agora eu preciso pegar essa String e transformar em uma view de volta, eu nem sei se é possível.

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível! Poderia dizer qual a necessidade de se gravar a View? Assim fica mais fácil de entender, o contexto, e poderemos auxiliar ...

Comment: Eu tenho uma lista de países e quando eu clico em um país ele muda de cor, eu precisava salvar os itens da minha lista em que já foram clicados e tiveram a cor alterada. Eu estou tentando usar o SharedPreferences para fazer isso.

Comment: Esta Lista está no SharedPreferences???

Comment: Não. no SharedPreferences eu apenas iria salvar a view da linha que mudou de cor, não da para salvar listView dentro do SharedPreferences, só aceita dados primitivos por isso estava tentando converter a view para String.

Comment: Uma sugestão simples: Salve uam String separada por ; com os nomes dos paises selecionados!

Comment: @daniel12345smith, Isso que você está fazendo não parece certo, ao chamar View.toString(), vc não está salvando uma View em uma String, você está pegando apenas o endereço de memória da view. Concordo com o Thiago Luiz Domacoski, voce pode salvar uma String separada por ; com os nomes dos paises selecionados.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo de como salvar a Lista no SharedPreferences:

```
// Constante com o nome do objeto q vamos salvar
    private static  final String LISTA = "LISTA";
    // Constante com o nome da propriedade
    private static  final String ITENS = "ITENS";
    private static  final String SEPARADOR = ";"; // este deve ter um coringa (caracter que não exista na lista!)

    /**
     * Transforma a lista em uma String e salva.
     * @param selecoes
     * @param context
     */
    public static void saveList(final List<String> selecoes, final Context context)
    {

        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(LISTA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(final String s : selecoes)
        {
            buffer.append(s);// adicionamos o item
            buffer.append(SEPARADOR);// adicionamos um separador

        }
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putString(ITENS, buffer.toString());
        editor.commit(); // commitamos os dados ...
    }


    public static List<String> loadList(final Context context)
    {

        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(LISTA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        final String valor = prefs.getString(ITENS, null);
       if(null == valor){ // não armazenamos nada ainda...
           return null;
       }

        final String[] lista = valor.split(SEPARADOR); /// quebramos a string em cada separador encontrado


        final List<String> retorno = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        for(final String s  : lista)
        {
            if(!"".equals(s))
            {
                retorno.add(s); // se não for vazia, adiciona na lista
            }
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

**Uma dica:**

Sugiro validar se um país já se encontra na lista antes de adicionar